# Azure API Management: Unable to define POST API with formdata

Tags: azure, post, azure-api-management, form-data

I am completely new to Azure management. I have a POST API to map to frontend and expose.
I have tried the Blank API option and tried to define a API in front end side and backend side.
The API I developed is a POST one, which needs a request body of type FORM-DATA and need a multipart file to be uploaded.

I am not sure how this is configured in the AZURE System. I am getting an error, since it is not hitting the backend.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVaYi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVaYi.png)

Comment: I am not able to generate the JSON spec for my API

Comment: I'm also new to apim, and if you just don't know how to add request header with 'multipart/form-data', you can add it in the Headers tag near the tag in your screenshot, and when testing the api, you can check 'Binary' in Request body then you can upload file.